# ScaleAnimator not working inside SequentialAnimation

Tags: qml, qt6

Following code gives the error:
"QML ScaleAnimator: setRunning() cannot be used on non-root animation nodes."
It works fine with Qt5 though. Cant we call animators inside Sequential animations:

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: c1
        color: "skyblue"
    }

    SequentialAnimation {
        running: true
        loops: Animation.Infinite

        ScaleAnimator {
            target: c1
            from: 1
            to: 0.5
            duration: 2000
            running: true
        }

        ScaleAnimator {
            target: c1
            from: 0.5
            to: 1
            duration: 2000
            running: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message sounds like it's just complaining about the line that say `running: true`. Have you tried removing those from the ScaleAnimators?

Comment: Yes I removed those lines and then error was gone, but then I found that no matter what duration I provide for animation, the animation remains the default 250ms.